# Kitten will not stop urinating on bed after surgery

Tags: cats, urination

My kitten was neuters a few weeks ago and ever since then as soon as I wake up in the morning he urinates on the bed. He has refused to use the bathroom correctly many times before for example if he is harassing his sister too much and I tell him or stop him cause shes meowing and running away he will always immediately urinate where he is not supposed to to let me know hes annoyed I stopped him from doing what he wanted to do.

For example if my mother comes over for a short visit she sometimes brings her dog so I put the kittens in the bedroom for the the 30 minutes she is here this upsets him as he doesnt want to go into the bedroom so he will urinate of defecate on the bed etc during this time.

Now that he has had surgery he just urinates on the bed every morning immediately after I wake up for the first 2 weeks i tried to be sympathetic and put him in correct bathroom place and cleaned it up only to have him then defecated beside the the bathroom place every time while I clean it up. now im not nearly as sympathetic about it I have tried yelling at him spanking him nothing works I am finish some renovations on my place and then I need put it for sale I cant have it smell like cat urine when prospective buyers here. I love him very much and he is a very affectionate kitten except bathroom problem.

Any advice on how to get him to use bathroom correctly appreciated as the only option I have left is to take him to the spca but i doubt anyone will want to adopt cat that pisses on everything so he will probably be put down.

If someone feels the need to say oh just pick him up and put him in the right place until he uses the bathroom correctly as a suggestion please don't i have tried that for almost 9 months it does not work.

EDIT: i have stuck him on the deck outside its not ideal and hes certainly unhappy about it but i guess i can keep him out there until i sell the place the urine smell is fairly easy to clean off the deck if i take him with me for showing's hopefully someone can come up with a better solution for me to try as it bothers his sister that hes not here with her and she clearly has done nothing to deserve not being able to cuddle up with him to goto sleep; but at least this way he wont be put down.

EDIT2: I only stop him from playing with his sister on very rare occasions usually when she starts hissing at him and i dont yell at him i simply pick him up a couple times when he gets close to her and he gets the message which is always followed by him immediately pissing or defacting somewhere he is not supposed to within minutes and before this incident it was the only time he wouldn't use the bathroom correctly.

Comment: The way you treat your cat is upsetting and sad.   First you shouldn't Stop him or stop her or stop them from having fun or fighting. Meowing or running from him doesn't mean she's being harrased. Be really really careful. You shoulnd't do that. They might be playing. Be even careful on how you stop it. Shouting at your cat or being mean to him is BAD! Remember your boy is not a human being. HE's not being EVIL Or even as u said "harrasing" his sister. These things don't exist in the animal kingdom.

Comment: Of course bringing a Dog to your appartment and throwing your boy in bedroom is bad. You are telling your cat that HIS house is it's his house is out of his control. 
Pissing means that he's marking his Territory. HE's pissed off. You are bringing a FOREIGN ENTITY to his territory and telling your cat to Buzz off this is not your territory anymore.

Comment: is there any other animals that is using the litterbox? is it only your cat and his sister? is the Dog also using the litterbox?

Comment: how often does the dog visits your appartment? who's using the litterbox other than your boy? And other points that should be taken into consideration

Comment: Please view the questions I have attached to yours, they will provide the answers your are looking for. It is very important that you do not hit or yell at your cat, he is NOT doing this to spite you. There is something bothering your cat (either mentally or physically) that is not being addressed. Abuse will only make it worse.

Answer (score 3):

You should let a vet examine him again, if possible another vet than did the surgery. If the urinating problem started right after surgery, it could be that his urinary tract or bladder was injured during it. What you interpret as him being stubborn and pissed off might actually be his cry for help because he's in constant pain.

In the long term you should think about searching for a new home for him. You write that he is very affectionate and you love him, but the wording of your post makes me doubt. If you really love him, you won't dump him in a shelter, but find a new family for him.

The problem might be that he's living with his sister. Male cats tend to be more solitary, while female cats can live in groups as well as solitary. You can read more about it in this related question:
[Why does one of my cats attack his siblings?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/21052/12501)

If your male cat feels like your female (or the dog) is invading *his* territory, he might feel like marking his territory with urine or feces. The renovations you did might be another factor. New paint, wallpapers or carpet all permeat the room with new smells. He might want to bring "his" scent back into "his" home.